# WebStorm Markdown Preview?

Tags: markdown, webstorm

Is there any way to edit and preview markdown files using WebStorm?

[This](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?id=5970) plugin is only for markdown language support, but I am looking for a plugin or tool which can let me edit the markdown in WebStorm and then preview in browser.

Comment: could you please update the type of plugin you used here? the link has apparently been lost

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Markdown Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?id=5970) you mentioned includes a Markdown preview tab (on the bottom), which looks like this:

[image]

If you really want to preview your file in a browser, you could install a Markdown -> HTML converter and run it from within Webstorm using [External Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/external-tools.html).

Comment: The same plugin is available for PhpStorm. Note that the Markdown plugin only supports standard Markdown with the default settings turned on. Go to File > Settings > Other Settings > Markdown to enable e.g. fenced code blocks as supported by Github and Bitbucket (multiline code blocks without indentation.) _Important remark_: you need to reload your project before these changes actually take effect!

Comment: I had to restart webstorm to get the Preview tab to show up.

Comment: Constantly crashes the whole IDE. Uses up all my memory, no matter how much I give it. Incredibly Slow.

Comment: I am having the same issues as others. The specific plugin I'm using is "Markdown Navigator" (I can't tell which plugin you are referencing as the pag went dead). I'd advise against using it for anything other than trivial documents.

Comment: I second the comments above: Markdown Navigator freezes the IDE. As @TimothyGonzalez noted in another answer, the "Markdown Support" plugin from JetBrains is better, lighter, and more stable.

Comment: Works well in PyCharm as of 2016.2.2.

Answer (score 8):

Jet Brains has their own markdown plugin. I'd suggest using it. I just switched from "Markdown Navigator", because it crashed a few times from using it heavily.

[image: Jet Brain's Markdown Plugin]

Comment: Also had stability issues using Markdown Navigator (Free Version), and resolved them by switching to Jet Brains Markdown support plugin.  It's a much nicer UI imo too.

Answer (score 8):

I'm looking for the same, but specifically for something offering live preview. I've found these two so far but haven't tried either one yet:

**[gfm-plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7701?pr=clion)**:

(free)

[image]

**[Markdown Navigator](http://vladsch.com/product/markdown-navigator)**:

(basic edition is free, extended edition which is required for live preview is $15)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in gfm-plugin internal links are not working :-(

Only Markdown Navigator correctly working with internal links to others .md documents